# Moving average in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database populated with power consumption over 20 years.
I want to query the average of the power consumption over every month, from a given month.

For example with this database,

```
date        power_consumption
2014/03/30  30
2014/04/30  40
2014/05/30  50
2014/06/30  20

The result would be, from 2014/04

month       average_so_far_from_april_2014
2014/04     40.0
2014/05     45.0
2014/06     36.667
```

If I cannot achieve this in one query, what query should I go for to retrieve the most useful data for this task? (My naive approach is to query the whole table out and calculate the average in my application.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the table of sub query against the consumption table which gets the unique months against the table of consumption, with a join condition that the year / month is less than or equal to the one from the sub query and use the AVG aggregate function on the power consumption from the table grouped by the year / month

Something like this:-

```
SELECT consumption_month, 
  AVG(b.power_consumption)
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y%m') AS consumption_month FROM consumption_table a
) a
INNER JOIN consumption_table b
ON consumption_month >= DATE_FORMAT(b.`date`, '%Y%m')
WHERE b.`date` >= '2014/04/01'
GROUP BY consumption_month
```

SQL fiddle:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16588/2

If you only had one record per month you could simplify it more by just doing a join of the table against itself without the need for the sub query.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` is for this kind of problems. The average is calculated for each distinct value of the expression the the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y/%m'), AVG(power_consumption)
FROM table_name
WHERE date > ...
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%y/%m')
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%y/%m')
```

You get the average for each month, `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%y/%m')` is year and month in format YYYY/MM

Comment: Well, nearly. I suppose.